# How to create multiple Google Analytics views through Google-Analytics-API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am planning to manage approx. 400 diff sites under one property by creating the dedicated view with hostname filter for each one. Is there any process to do this task without manually creating the view and making filters?

Ex: we have multiple websites like abc.com, bcd.com, cde.com etc. and I have created a property to manage this all website by creating google analytics views so each view will have data for each one website like view 1 have data for abc.com and to do this i have to create hostname filter and that task need to do manually if you have diff - 2 site.

I'm looking a way to do this by any sort of automation.

Please help!

Advance Thanks,
Nandan

Comment: Look in your account planning, is not possible to manage as you describe, the limit for accounts are 200 per email, 50  property per account and 20 views per property. So is not a option a single property with ~400 views
properties .https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1102152?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

The google analytics management api has methods for inserting updating and deleting web proprieties and views

[Refrence](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/insert)

Last i knew this was still in beta and you had to apply for access.  I am not seeing any note on that in the documentation anymore so it may be out of beta i will contact the team for verification.

Write operations in the Management API
Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources no longer require whitelisting. The default daily limit for all Write operations in the Management API is 50 writes/day. See Limits and Quotas page for more information.

Update: Apparently its out of beta you should be all set.

> Release 2018-02-22 (February 22, 2018)
>   Write operations in the Management API
>   Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources no longer require whitelisting. The default daily limit for all Write operations in the Management API is 50 writes/day. See Limits and Quotas page for more information.

Comment: I was trying this API by putting some field value like property id, account id and uses Authorization Google oAuth 2.0 but every time it throws an error of 400, 500 etc.

Comment: Hey DalmTo,  I was trying through your reference link so when you open that link on the right side there is an option of try it now it contains few fields like account id, property id and authentication method, In the account id  i have putting my account id and similar with property id and for the authtication there is two option oAuth and API key i am using there oAUth but getting error 400, field is reuiqred something.

Comment: I will let the team know the try me isn't working on that page its probably a permission issue.   Thanks for letting me know

Comment: sumitted a bug report.  I can verify that the try me is not working https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79653874